# Segfault when deleting nodes from a templated linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Right now I'm working on a *LinkedList* project, with the clear method acting very strangely at the moment:

```
template <class Elm>
void LinkedSortedList<Elm>::clear() {
     if (head != NULL) {
        LinkedNode<Elm>* currentNode = head;
        LinkedNode<Elm>* nextNode;
        if (head->next != NULL) {
           nextNode = head->next;
        }
        while (currentNode != NULL) {  
           nextNode = currentNode->next; 
           delete currentNode;
           currentNode = nextNode;

        }
        head = NULL;
     }
}
```

Everything appears to work properly until the line

```
nextNode = currentNode->next;
```

where both *currentNode's* and *nextNode's* values are switched to two completely different, extremely large values. Before that line, both variables have the proper values in them. When

```
delete currentNode;
```

is called in the next line, I immediately get a segfault, even though it doesn't look like the address of the node was changed in any way.

Is there anything that might be causing the pointers to point to two completely different places all of the sudden?

EDIT: Here's the LinkedNode class,

```
#ifndef _LinkedNodeClass_
#define _LinkedNodeClass_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Elm> class LinkedNode {
public:

  Elm value;            // The data value
  LinkedNode *next;     // Pointer to the next node

  // Simple inline constructor:  initialize values
  LinkedNode(Elm newval = 0, LinkedNode* newptr = NULL)
      {value = newval; next = newptr;} 
  ~LinkedNode() {delete &next;}

  // Inline print function:  print the node's value
  void print() {cout << value;}

};

#endif
```

Comment: Did you check the destructor to make sure it's not causing the segfault?

Comment: And you do remember to initialize the `LinkedNode::next` member to zero when a node is created (e.g. in its constructor)?

Comment: And you're not violating [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)?

Comment: are you sure `currentNode` is modified by `nextNode = currentNode->next;` and not earlier? do you test in debug mode? what is type of your element in your test? does it have non-trivial destructor?

Comment: `while (currentNode != NULL)      
 {
  nextNode = currentNode->next; /*head->next                            
  basically same as nextNode = head->next*/
  delete currentNode; /*delete head*/
  currentNode = nextNode; /*head->next*   
 }`

So question really is what is head->next pointing to?
Also what is being done in destructors?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I should clarify, the destructor is causing the segfault, but the destructor is being called by the `delete currentNode;` call right after the `nextNode = currentNode->next`.

Comment: If the destructor is causing the segfault why didn't you include the code for it?

Comment: @user3365835 `~LinkedNode() {delete &next;}` **Hell why** are you doing this?? Just remove the delete from there!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Doesn't this class need a destructor to delete properly? If I didn't have the destructor the *next pointer wouldn't be deleted. Wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Comment: @user3365835 - so you waited for a clear() function to test your destructor?  Do you have a function (maybe a remove() function) in your LinkedList class that simply removes a single link?  If so, then your destructor should have failed there.

Comment: @user3365835 - The delete operator requires you to provide the address returned by new.  You are not doing that in your code.  Instead, you're giving delete some odd address (the address of a pointer).

Comment: @user3365835 _'Doesn't this class need a destructor to delete properly?'_ No! You surely don't want to delete the `next` node, when the actual node is going to be deleted.

Comment: @user3365835 -  Maybe you should do what I suggested earlier -- write the function to delete a *single* node (call it remove() and give it a position in the list to delete).  Once you have that working, then clear() is just calling remove(0) until the list is empty.  If you did things this way, you more than likely would never had written the LinkedNode class with the faulty destructor in the way you wrote it.

Comment: You can take my word on it or not, but `delete next;` is *not* something want to do *at all*, much less in a destructor. You want the linked list containing and managing these nodes to walk the path of destruction; *not* the nodes themselves. It may seem convenient, but imagine loading your list with 10,000+ nodes. Hmm. How big is your implementation's call-stack? Because you're about to enter a recursive descent 10,000 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything that might be causing the pointers to point to two completely different places all of the sudden?

Yes! If you don't have `LinkedNode<T>::next` initialized to `NULL` correctly in the class constructors or assignment operators, they might hold an uninitialized or invalid value. Many compilers use special values to indicate uninitialized pointers in debug version.

This might also happen for *'dangling'* pointers that have been already deleted earlier. This might well be the case, because in your destructor you are already deleting the `next` pointer:

```
~LinkedNode() {delete &next;}
```

Thus `next` will be invalid in the next iteration step in the `clear()` function. Even worse, the syntax you are using is valid, but semantically wrong here: You are trying to delete the address where the `next` pointer variable itself lives (that certainly never was allocated with `new`).